# layer priority over basemap

Tags: leaflet, carto

Hello I was trying to but together a quick and dirty bing/osm  map using leaflet and [leaflet plugin](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins). My problem comes in when adding a layer from cartodb.The points do not show and I am not getting any errors, however when I change opacity on the tile where my points should be they show up. So it looks like the base maps are taking priority over my layer. Is there a way to fix this?

```
    function main() {
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
            center: new L.LatLng(39.095,-75.54),
            zoom: 2
    });

    var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    var bing = new L.BingLayer("AulNwbEkrE4P0VQrC8JI3SKoJDC4A9V63I8q4tixTNo6HUkfUyjWJuXSgpgysdZ5");
        map.addLayer(bing);bing.bringToBack();
        map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers({'OSM':osm, "Bing":bing}, {}));
          cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://centuryeng.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/a7fd6eb2-f6ee-11e3-b807-0e73339ffa50/viz.json')
            .addTo(map)
            .on('done', function (layer) {

            });
    console.log(map);
    }

    window.onload = main;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the desired basemap as: `var basemap = L.Tilelayer (drop "new")`... They're all being added as overlay layers as is